# OOP in general - Class information in RAM

Tags: oop, ram

Is it absolutely necessary, that a programming language saves the class info (e.g. in Objective-C 2 bytes) to know the "specification" (e.g. `Integer`: 4 bytes; `String`: 8 bytes; ...) of the `object`?
Because of the polymorphism the program has to check at runtime whether the object has the correct `type` (for methods; messages) right?
Consumes this much resources? Mainly because you create more and more classes in order to maintain a proper structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely necessary. The object (ie a reference) of a class is stored in RAM. It uses a very small no. f bytes because it only stores the memory **address**.

Checking doesn't take place a runtime, it takes place during compilation. This doesn't cause any extra usage of memory. Creating classes, methods doesn't increase memory usage but (if only slightly) increases compilation time. Storing data (objects/references, numbers, strings, etc.) uses memory. Only when you create objects does the language machine allocate and use memory.

Comment: But how knows the program how the data are built up behind a reference? "Something" must identifies a object, whether the additional class information of an object or a whole class pool.

Comment: d program doesn't need know. It has been checked by the compiler that everything is fine and there are no incorrect method calls or incorrect references (or objects)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it absolutely necessary

No.

For example, by default, C++ doesn't store any type information.  Each object simply stores a [pointer to a table of function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vtable), in order to implement virtual function calls.

In C++, by default, all the type-checking is done at compile-time.  This only changes if you start doing "interesting" things like [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast), which requires run-time type-checking, and therefore type information to be stored in objects.

Comment: @LucaNateMahler: Yes, but not in the sense that your question was asking about; it's not used to "check at runtime whether the object has the correct type".

Comment: So we can definitely say that OOP wastes more memory than languages with primitives do?

Comment: "wastes" doesn't seem really neutral. OOP languages have different features and are generally much less compact (due to many other reasons than the function table).

Comment: @LucaNateMahler: It's not a "waste".  To obtain the same functionality in a non-OOP language, you would need to implement this mechanism manually.  So it would take up space either way.